# Javadoc @link to Kotlin classes

Tags: java, kotlin, javadoc

This is my javadoc

```
/**
 * If you wish to add this fragment to your activity, you must implement {@link com.example.app.BlaActivity BlaActivity}
 *
 * @return an instance of BlaFragment
 */
```

`BlaActivity` is a Kotlin class. When I hover over the method with the javadoc above, the popup says:

```
If you wish to add this fragment to your activity, you must implement

Returns:
        an instance of BlaFragment
```

So, it does not show my Kotlin class in the popup. However it works fine when I use a Java class.

Javadoc has no support for Kotlin classes?

Comment: Where do you develop?

Comment: @dralexnumber Android Studio

Answer (score 25):

Kotlin have different syntax for linking. Base on [kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html)

Instead of

```
{@link com.example.app.BlaActivity}
```

Use `[` like this

```
[com.example.app.BlaActivity]
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the question was asking. The question was about referencing a Kotlin class in documentation on a Java file, not writing documentation in a Kotlin file.

Comment: @Dennis yes you right! and i didn't remember why i wrote this answer!

Answer (score -1):

It works fine in my project, please try to update your kotlin version and plugin to the latest version because mine are all latest.

Comment: Mine latest too: 1.3.0-release-Studio3.2-1